# How to parse and decode URI in Java to URI components?

Tags: java, url, decode

I am trying to find a method that would parse an URL, decoded it and returned the decoded components in an unambiguous way.

[URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) isn't a right fit, because it may return ambiguous String, e.g.

```
URLDecoder.decode("http://www.google.com?q=abc%26def", "UTF-8")
```

returns:

```
http://www.google.com?q=abc&def
```

So the information about escaped & is lost.

I'd like to have something like:

```
DecodedUrlComponents cmp = GreatURLDecoder.decode(url);
Map<String, List<String>> decodedQuery = cmp.getQuery();
decodedQuery.get("q").get(0); //returns "abc&def"
```

How do I accomplish that?

EDIT:
Thanks for the responses, but my question was a bit different: I would like to get **decoded** components in an unambiguous way, so neither of the following does what I need:

- `new URI("http://www.google.com?q=abc%26def").getRawQuery()` returns encoded query: `q=abc%26def`
- `new URI("http://www.google.com?q=abc%26def").getQuery()` returns ambiguous value: `q=abc&def`
- `URLDecoder.decode("http://www.google.com?q=abc%26def", "UTF-8")` returns ambiguous value: `http://www.google.com?q=abc&def`
- `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://www.google.com?q=abc%26def").build(true).getQueryParams()` - close, but still not what I want, because it returns a map of encoded params: `{q=[abc%26def]}`

Answer (score 2):

With spring framework (org.springframework.web.util) you can do the following:

```
URI uri = <your_uri_here>;
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uri);
UriComponents uriComponents = uriComponentsBuilder.build();
String path = uriComponents.getPath();
MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = uriComponents.getQueryParams(); //etc.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not properly decode query parameters with percent encoding. So I recommend against using it if your URL potentially contains query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use an implementation of [`javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html). One example would be `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyUriInfo`. If you're using maven you only need to add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then the following code should do what you want:

```
UriInfo ui = new ResteasyUriInfo(new URI("http://www.google.com?q=abc%26def"));
List<String> qValues = ui.getQueryParameters().get("q");
for (String q : qValues) {
    System.out.println(q);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it does its job. I am not super-happy with it though - dependency on JAX-RS just for the sake of parsing and decoding URLs seems an overkill

Comment: Agreed, it's quite a lot of extra stuff. You might be better off just copying the class from their source repository and include just that one.

Comment: Also if you're using Jersey 2 instead of RESTEasy for JAX-RS, you can use `org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriComponent.decodeQuery(URI, boolean)` and related `decode*` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com?test=34%3fg";
URL testUrl = new java.net.URL(url);
System.out.println(testUrl.getQuery());
```

Should print test=34%3fg.

Answer (score 0):

`URLDecoder` does not split your URL into components, it simply translates the String representation thereof to a specific format, as hinted by it's JavaDoc and its signature, which returns a String. As others mentioned, you should just construct a `URL` object from your string, which exposes all the functionality you need. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

Answer (score -1):

Generate a `java.net.URL` from your URL-String and then use mwthods like `url.getQuery()`, `url.getProtocol()`, `url.getHost()` etc. - it's all there.